# JavaFX detecting collision with the Stage

Tags: java, javafx, stage

I created a program that creates a small black circle on the screen that is movable using W A S D keyboard keys. Now I am trying to make so that the black circle would not go out of Stage bounds ( which it currently does ). My idea is to create a method that takes 2 arguments: circle and the stage. The method would work like this:

```
if(circle.getBoundsInParent().intersects(stage)) { 
     MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0 
}
```

This method is supposed to check whether the circle interesects with the stage, if it does, then it will set the balls movement speed to zero, thus preventing him from going through the stage. However, the

```
circle.getBoundsInParent().intersects(stage))
```

code does not work. It says that the stage cannot be converted to bounds. What I need to do in order to check for figure and stage collision and prevent the figure from moving out of Stage bonds?

This is my current code.

```
package pong;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  private static int MOVEMENT_SPEED = 10;
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    final Circle circle = createCircle();   
    final Group group = new Group( circle);
    Scene scene = new Scene(group,  700, 700);
    move(scene, circle);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private void move(Scene scene, final Circle circle) {
     scene.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
         switch (event.getCode()) {
             case W:    circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() - MOVEMENT_SPEED); 
                break;
             case D: circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + MOVEMENT_SPEED); 
                break;
             case S:  circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + MOVEMENT_SPEED); 
                break;
             case A:  circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() - MOVEMENT_SPEED); 
                break;
         }
     });
}

private Circle createCircle() {
   final Circle circle = new Circle(10, 10, 10, Color.BLACK);
   circle.setOpacity(0.7);
   return circle;
}

// This method should detect collision and prevent it from happening
private void detectCollsion(Circle circle, Stage primaryStage) {
  /*  if(circle.getBoundsInParent().intersects(primaryStage)) {
        MOVEMENT_SPEED = 0;
    }   */
 }    
}
```

Comment: I think rather than writing a method for detecting collision and taking all the pain to detect the side on which the circle is going to collide, the same can be achieved by adding a condition to your switch statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. I feel this would be opt for your situation.

You are using the circle's `centerX` and `centerY` properties for movement of the circle. These properties return the position of the center of the circle and we can use the same for collision detection. The position of the exact point on the circumference of the circle which will intersect with the edge of the scene will be the sum of this value and the radius of the circle.

We can always get the reference to the scene (`node.getScene()`) and therefore find the bounds where the circle is allowed to travel. In your case, we already have the reference to the scene, so we just use it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    private static int MOVEMENT_SPEED = 10;
    private static int RADIUS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Circle circle = createCircle();
        final Group group = new Group( circle);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group,  700, 700);
        move(scene, circle);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void move(Scene scene, final Circle circle) {
        scene.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case W:
                    if(circle.getCenterY() > RADIUS)
                        circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() - MOVEMENT_SPEED);
                    break;
                case D:
                    if(circle.getCenterX() < scene.getWidth() - RADIUS)
                        circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + MOVEMENT_SPEED);
                    break;
                case S:
                    if(circle.getCenterY() < scene.getHeight() - RADIUS)
                        circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + MOVEMENT_SPEED);
                    break;
                case A:
                    if(circle.getCenterX() > RADIUS)
                        circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() - MOVEMENT_SPEED);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    private Circle createCircle() {
        final Circle circle = new Circle(10, 10, RADIUS, Color.BLACK);
        circle.setOpacity(0.7);
        return circle;
    }
}
```